# Want to map attribute of an object from a List to an Object

Tags: mapstruct

While traversing through ACROD, there is a list and want to map the first object from that list to my domain object.

@Mapping(source="insuranceSvcRqs[0].policyQuoteInqRqsAddRqsAndPolicyQuoteInqRqs[0].producers[0].generalPartyInfo.nameInfos[0].commlName.commercialName",
            target = "producer.commercialName")

I tried this one but it did not work. All blogs that I have searched has LIST to LIST mapping. Mine is LIST.first() to Domain Object mapping.

Comment: Did you checkout Mapstructs example repo on GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [example](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-iterable-to-non-iterable). It explains how to map a collection to an object and what element to take (first, last) based on a qualifier.

Comment: @Nitin: was this helpful?